# Select multiple passes only the last selected value in request

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, jquery-select2

I have a select2 field like which accepts multiple attribute:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 m-input--solid">
    <select class="form-control m-select2 m-input--solid" id="m_select2_3" name="collegeCourses" multiple>
        @foreach($courseCategories as $courseCategory)
        <optgroup label="{{$courseCategory}}">
            @foreach($courseNames->$courseCategory as $courseName)
            <option value="{{$courseName}}" >
                {{$courseName}}
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </optgroup>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Note that I have specified `multiple` in my select form.

example input:
[image]

But the $request has only the last selected value!!
[image]

also manually checking also displays that $request has only last value

```
$input = Input::all();
$roles = $input["collegeCourses"];
echo $roles; //output: Mrs. Eldora Blick
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<select class="form-control m-select2 m-input--solid" id="m_select2_3" name="collegeCourses" multiple>
```

you have to pass the name se an array like:

```
collegeCourses[]
```

so that it can accept multiple selected values. And you can get these values by using `foreach()` loop like:

```
foreach($collegeCourses as $course)
{
  // do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add [] to the name of the element so it becomes collegeCourses[] instead and can be treated as array.

Answer (score 0):

use square brackets with name attribute

```
name="collegeCourses[]"
```